# Python pandas: Calculating distance ran between two lists?

Tags: python, pandas, compare, rank, edit-distance

I have two lists of rankings A and B like this:

A:

```
rank  asn
1     345
2     34567
3     123
```

B:

```
rank  asn
1     123
2     34567
3     345
```

I would like to compare the two lists using a correlation method to see how different the lists are from each other. Currently I am using "Spearman" correlation method but the problem is that every time I run it I get different result. 
Here is my code:

## calculating correlation rank

```
a['asn'].corr(b['asn'], method='spearman')
```

Can anybody help with a way to compare the two lists?

Comment: I'm getting a `0.5` consistently with 'spearman'. Are your inputs changing in between ?

Comment: I am also getting `0.5`. The problem is probably somewhere else. Perhaps reading the values in the first place? Are you getting them from a file or a db?